# How to convert CSV and TSV files to PDF?

Tags: pdf, csv

I want to convert my online store's CSV and TSV files into .PDF format. How to convert? Is there any solution?

Comment: What platform (Mac/Windows/Other)? How do you want the files formatted? Do you have e.g. Microsoft Office available?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what OS you are using & what tools you have installed, I am suggesting these very general online tools which can be used manually :

(1) https://convertio.co/csv-pdf/

(2) https://cloudconvert.com/csv-to-pdf

(3) https://www.beautifyconverter.com/tsv-to-pdf-converter.php

(4) https://wtools.io/convert-tsv-to-pdf

In case you want to automate this, eg to generate every week or every month, you might want to specify what OS & tools you are going to use.

On Windows (& Mac) with MS Excel, it is very easy to manually or automatically "EXPORT" to various formats including PDF.

With Free Office Suites, you can achieve that on all common Platforms including Linux.

Comment: Oh, that Point is nice to include ! Doubt/Concern : I think, when viewing the CSV/TSV in a text editor then MAC Print will show it like Plain text itself without fancy formatting like MS Excel would give ! I think, we have to use a tool which "knows" CSV/TSV to Print with formatting , @Tetsujin

Comment: The **built-in** rendering with the **built-in** reader looks much nicer than some of the alternatives , @Tetsujin

Comment: Nice ! I hope the OP comes back , to check the Answer & the various Comments , including the Comment to the Question Post. I am sure OP will get good Ideas to achieve this through these. @Tetsujin

Comment: Prem - I've moved all this into an actual answer so it doesn't just wallow down in comments. Thanks for your interaction, it made me test something I'd not actually tried before  :)

Answer (score 1):

*Let me transfer comments into an answer, just to make it a little more permanent…*

On Mac you can 'print' anything directly to PDF; it's built-in at system level.

As a test I grabbed a sample csv file online to see exactly what would happen. Mac has a built-in 'reader' for a lot of file types. You just select the file & hit the spacebar & it will show you what it looks like [Quicklook]. Above that is what happens if I make it open in a text reader, which is to be expected. The formatting on Quicklook wouldn't win any prizes for beauty, but it's accurate & it picked a decent, legible font. This is what it would print with no further editing.  I honestly don't think it's a bad attempt.

[image]

Just as an experiment, I told the Mac to just 'print the file' [literally select the file in Finder (like 'Explorer'), then Cmd/P with no other intervention]. It launched Numbers [which is the macOS equivalent of Excel], sent the print job then closed it again. This is a screenshot, of a scan … of the print. It auto-generated the bold & header demarcation without me asking. Even better than the Quicklook version, imo. The print itself is sharper than the scan, of course.

[image]

So this is what the Mac will do to a 'plain' csv file, with no other user intervention.

This is a cleaner screenshot, from Numbers

[image]

Once you have your shiny new layout, you can turn it into a pdf in the same way as any file on the Mac - Open the Print dialog,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>  , then bottom left, PDF > Save as PDF…

[image]

Comment: In general , that is good +1 , but I hope OP will not come back to say that this is a Windows or Linux Case. @Tetsujin

Comment: It will still be perhaps useful for anyone else finding the question later. I did forget to show the last step - how to turn any file into a PDF from the Print dialog, so I'll add that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/), a powerful tool to convert files from one markup format into another.

```bash
pandoc -o output.pdf input.csv
```

The format of the input and output can be specified explicitly using `-f/--from` and `-t/--to` respectively, otherwise, pandoc will attempt to guess it from the extensions of the filenames. Also, instead of an input file, an absolute URI may be given:

```bash
pandoc -f csv -t pdf -o output.pdf https://www.url.io/path/to/input.csv
```

Type `pandoc --list-input-formats` and `pandoc --list-output-formats` to know the formats in which you can move.

#### Creating a PDF

By default, pandoc will use [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) as an intermediate format and some installed *latex-to-pdf engine* in order to create the PDF. Alternatively, you can use HTML (requires `wkhtmltopdf`) or Unix -ms macros as intermediate format,

```bash
pandoc -t ms -o output.pdf input.csv
```

See the [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf) for more details.